# No processes are listening on 80, and yet my GCE instance is still receiving traffic. Are there ways of hiding a socket?

Tags: apache, nginx, networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So - google compute instance, Debian 10, trying to set up Node/PM2/NGINX.

When I visit my instance's external ip in my browser, it sends back the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. Strange - I didn't install Apache, and I didn't know it came with the debian image I'm using with GCE.

Also, the text on this default page says that it's an html doc stored at /var/www/html/index.html. But when I check, it isn't there. There isn't even a /www folder in /var.

When I check running services using `sudo systemctl status`, I get this back:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

So instead, I run `sudo service --status-all`. Here's the output:

```
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  binfmt-support
 [ - ]  cron
 [ - ]  dbus
 [ + ]  docker
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  lxc
 [ ? ]  lxc-net
 [ - ]  postgresql
 [ - ]  procps
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ - ]  supervisor
 [ - ]  udev
 [ - ]  x11-common*
```

It occurs to me now that Apache might not be a "service", but there might still be an apache process running and listening on 80. idk, linux noob here. So.

When I check who's listening on 80 (`sudo netstat -tulnp | grep :80`), there's no results.

So...no apache service running (unless there's something i don't understand about why `systemctl` is down). No processes listening on port 80. And yet, when I copy the external ip from GCE and enter it into my browser, I'm served this default page.

I'm reasonably confident it's the correct ip - when i alter the firewall provided by GCP to prevent traffic entering on 80, I can't access the instance - no default apache page.

on top of it, when I boot up nginx to listen on 80 and reverse proxy to my node app on 8080, *I still get sent to the default apache page* when I enter it into my browser. it seems that nginx is the only thing listening on 80 (checked via netstat - a process appears when I boot up nginx, and disappears when I stop the nginx service).

There's clearly something I don't understand at work here. I'm off to research more, but if any of you lords of SO have some insight, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see docker is running, have you tried checking `docker ps` and stopping and running docker containers ?

Comment: Hmmm - I gave it a shot, seems like there aren't any containers running.

Comment: 3 Ways to Find Out Which Process Listening on a Particular Port: https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/

Comment: The Debian 10 image in GCE does not come with apache installed by default. I'm wondering if you are inadvertently redirecting traffic through the NGINX service. Can you post your NGINX config?